# Android - Breakdown Error Reported

Tags: android, eclipse

full error report

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setAlpha
  at       app1.com.com.DetailActivity.updatePreviousButton(DetailActivity.java:195)
  at app1.com.com.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:115)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

recently my app reported following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.ImageView.setAlpha
```

which was caused from following function

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void updatePreviousButton() {
    if (currentPosition == 0) {
        prevBtn.setAlpha(0.5f);
        prevBtn.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        prevBtn.setAlpha(1f);
        prevBtn.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

its happening from setAlpha line, any idea how to rectify it.

Comment: try using prevBtn.setImageAlpha(int). Also remove @SuppressLint("NewApi")

Comment: Why people Ask question and Run away

Comment: i m here.... just looking for some solution...

Comment: its showing error in   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
(too)

Comment: did you try changing setAlpha ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what API version you are using because `setAlpha` was put in, in a SDK version greater than you min SDK. So obviously any SDK below the SDK that it was implemented will break because it does not exist.

Edit:

as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha(int)) that method was deprecated in API version 16 so it may have been removed in a later version

Comment: @Pooja what is `prevBtn`

Comment: @Pooja that is not what i asked, I want to know what object that is

Comment: if what you say is true that this is happening on 2.2 then dell for some reason removed that from the SDK. I would recommend dropping 2.2 all together anyway since it is only 0.4% of the market now, no point is supporting it anymore